# Describe the units and maximal ideas in $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be a fixed prime integer and let $R$ be the set of all rational integers in the form $a/b$ where $b = p^k$ for an integer $k \geq 0$ and an arbitrary integer $a$. $R$ is also a subring of $\mathbb{Z}$. Describe all units in $R$. How many maximal ideals are there? Describe the maximal ideals.

Regarding the units, I got $a/b$ where $a = p^k, k\geq 0$.

However, I am unsure about the maximal ideal. I read through another answer on this question ([Describe units and maximal ideals in these two PIDs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607445/describe-units-and-maximal-ideals-in-these-two-pids)) that states the prime ideal is $(0)$ and $\{qa/p^k : a\in \mathbb{Z}, k\geq 0\}$ where $q\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q \neq p$. Are all of these prime ideals maximal? Does that then mean there are an infinite number of maximal ideas in $R$?

Comment: Allow me a couple of corrections. First of all, in your definition it is better to specify that $a$ is an arbitrary integer. Then you should clarify that $R$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$. And finally, the units of $R$ are the numbers of the form $\pm p^{t}$, with $t \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Thank you for your suggestions. Do you mean units where $a= \pm p^t$ with $t \in \mathbb{Z}$ or in general the numbers $\pm p^t$ with $t \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I mean the second one, yes.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of hints.

It's perhaps simpler if you write your $R$ as the set of rational numbers of the form
$$
ap^k
$$
where $a$ is not divisible by $p$ or is zero and $k$ is any integer.

From this representation it should be clear that in order for the element to be invertible we need $a=\pm1$.

Now let $I$ be a prime ideal in $R$ and consider $J=I\cap\mathbb{Z}$. Then $J$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$. Is it prime? Can you find a way to build a prime ideal of $R$ starting from a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$? And when does this construction fail?